# Powershell | Array get the longest string

Tags: arrays, powershell

I would like to get the longest string in an array, without looping through the whole array with foreach or do...until.

I tried this:

```
$Namelength = ($array | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum.ToString().Length
```

*It seems to work with numbers.
But not with strings (my strings contain "," "." "-" and "_")*

I am somehow just getting some long strings, but not the longest - It is more like an average value.

Any idea to solve that?

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@Kayasax's answer will give you the string(value) for the longest string. The reason your code didn't work was because you measured the items in the array, not the length. For that, you need to specify the `-Property Length` parameter in `Measure-Object`, like this:

```
PS> ("lalala","hehe","hi" | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1=@("test";"coucou","helloword")
$array1 | sort length -desc | select -first 1
```

Comment: Simple and nice - thx. Do you by any chance know, why my code does not work?

Comment: or `$array1 | Sort-Object Length | Select -Last 1`. This is a bit more readable.